# Trying to delete items from a multidimensional array (html,javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have table that is created that shows each item added to the array. In the last row of each column is an action field that lets you either edit or delete from the row. I am not sure how I am supposed to accomplish this. What I have so far does not work properly.

```
function del(item) {

    participantList.splice(item,1);
    displayLIst();
}

function addInfo() { 
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if(fname !='' && lname !="" && email !='') {
        participantList[count] = new Object();
        participantList[count].Fname = fname;
        participantList[count].Lname = lname;
        participantList[count].Email = email;
        participantList[count].Action = "<button onclick='del("+count+")'>Delete</button>" + "<button onclick='edit("+count+")'>Edit</button>";
        count++;

        document.getElementById("fname").value ="";
        document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        }
        displayList();

}
```

I want to delete every object from the specified row in the array.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the elements and putting them into the participant list?
Do you have references to the elements? Can you include the HTML as well and all the related code to what you want to do?

Below is how I would get all of the elements, and remove one.

You can remove an element by calling .remove() on it

Here is my example code: http://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/cxt170re/

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var item = listItems[1];
item.remove();
```

querySelectorAll creates a live node list
I grab one of those elements (index 1) and delete it with Element.remove();

Check out the fiddle to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a current working version:

```
var participantList = [];
var edit = function(item) {};
var del =  function(item) {

    participantList.splice(item,1);
    displayList();
};

function addInfo() { 
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var count = participantList.length;
if(fname !='' && lname !="" && email !='') {
  var item = {};
  item.Fname = fname;
  item.Lname = lname;
  item.Email = email;
  item.Action = "<button onclick='del("+count+")'>Delete</button><button onclick='edit("+count+")' disabled>Edit</button>";

  participantList.push(item);

    document.getElementById("fname").value ="";
    document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    }
    displayList();

};

var displayList = function () {
  // clean previous data
  console.log(participantList);
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
  var content = "";
  for(var i = 0; i<participantList.length; i++) {
    content += "<tr>";
    content += "<td>" + participantList[i].Fname + "</td>";
    content += "<td>" + participantList[i].Lname + "</td>";
    content += "<td>" + participantList[i].Email + "</td>";
    content += "<td>" + participantList[i].Action + "</td>";
    content += "</tr>"
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<table>" + content + "    </table>";
};
```

With the following HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" />
<input type="text" id="lname" />
<input type="text" id="email" />

<button onclick="addInfo()">
  Add
</button>

<div id="results">
```

EDIT: Missing JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/d64314uk/